# Is it possible with AspectJ to prevent the next aspect from executing in order?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a method annotated with two aspects:

```
@Aspect1Annotation
@Aspect2Annotation
public SomeResult handle() {
    // some code
    return null;
}
```

I would like the first annotaion to execute and based on its results prevent execution of the second aspects logic.

How to do it with AspectJ? Please help.

**EDIT:**

I am developing an application which has multiple methods with these annotations:

```
@Monitored
@Secured(Permission.SOME_PERMISSION)
@Audited
public SomeResult handle() {
    // some code
    return null;
}
```

1. The MonitoringAspect logic must always run despite security permissions.
2. The permission check should be done after the MonitoringAspect and if access is denied, a runtime exception should be thrown.
3. AuditAspect logic should only be executed if access is allowed.

Comment: Native AspectJ or Spring AOP? The answers would be different. If AspectJ, native or annotation-based syntax?

Comment: @kriegaex native AspectJ with annotation-based syntax

Comment: Oh, too bad. Native syntax is much more elegant and concise. But OK, I can create an answer for @AspectJ syntax, too. But please also put your question into context, explaining what exactly you want to achieve, not just focusing on how (suppress aspect execution) you want to achieve it. That way, you are limiting the space of possible solutions. This is called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). Otherwise, my answer will be correct, but maybe will does not help you much.

Comment: Thanks, I can answer later after work. But one remark first: _"AuditAspect logic should only be executed if access is allowed."_ That sounds illogical. The audit aspect probably is meant to determine whether access is allowed or not, is it not? Therefore, it always has to be executed. I rather guess that the audit aspect should prevent the **target method** from being executed. Correct?

Comment: "Secured" aspect is meant to determine whether access is allowed or not. If access is not allowed, neither the target method nor the audit logic should be executed. Thanks!

Comment: Oh OK. You did not explicitly mention the secured aspect in your enumeration, only implicitly. So actually, you have 3 aspects, not just 2. See, this is the problem about questions without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The annotations as such do not do anything, nor are they necessary for aspects to kick in, because aspects can also determine joinpoints in other ways than filtering for annotations. Using marker annotations is completely optional. I really don't know why so many developers think they need annotations for each and every aspect. I hardly use them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a combination of

- `@Around` advice in your aspects and
- [`@DeclarePrecedence`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html) for declaring aspect precedence.

This way, you can chain advice execution exactly the way you want to and dynamically decide whether each advice should

- proceed to the next advice in the chain depending on its precedence (or to the target method, if there is no more advice in the chain), or
- not to proceed but return a result calculated by the advice itself, or
- to throw an exception instead of returning something.

Of course, you can combine these things, e.g. proceed but discard or modify the result or proceed, but depending on the result still throw an exception.

If you just want to decide to either throw an exception or just pass through the call and its result unchanged, depending on authorisation status, of course a simple `@Before` advice will also do and `@Around` is unnecessary.

Here is a simple example with 2 aspects, which you can easily adapt to your situation. Feel free to ask directly related follow-up questions in comments, if anything is unclear about the sample code.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("  " + doSomething());
    }
  }

  public static String doSomething() {
    return "doing something";
  }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Random;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class FirstAspect {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  @Around("execution(String doSomething())")
  public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("FirstAspect");
    switch (RANDOM.nextInt(3)) {
      // Do not proceed to 2nd aspect, create own return value
      case 0: return "1st aspect";
      // Proceed to 2nd aspect, modify response
      case 1: return joinPoint.proceed() + " - 1st aspect";
      // Proceed to 2nd aspect, return response unchanged
      default: return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Random;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("FirstAspect, SecondAspect")
public class SecondAspect {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  @Around("execution(String doSomething())")
  public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("SecondAspect");
    switch (RANDOM.nextInt(3)) {
      // Do not proceed to target method, create own return value
      case 0: return "2nd aspect";
      // Proceed to target method, but modify return value
      case 1: return joinPoint.proceed() + " - 2nd aspect";
      // Proceed to target method, return response unchanged
      default: return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
  }
}
```

The console log might look like this:

```
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  doing something - 2nd aspect - 1st aspect
FirstAspect
  1st aspect
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  2nd aspect - 1st aspect
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  doing something - 1st aspect
FirstAspect
  1st aspect
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  doing something
FirstAspect
  1st aspect
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  doing something - 1st aspect
FirstAspect
  1st aspect
FirstAspect
SecondAspect
  doing something - 2nd aspect
```

You can see how sometimes the result is passed through unchanged by both aspects, sometimes only one of the aspect or both aspects modify the result or how sometimes the second aspect is not even called, because the first one does not proceed. Instead of not proceeding, throwing an exception would also be possible.